# Image isn't loading getting illegal argument exception input == null

Tags: java, bufferedimage, illegalargumentexception, game-development, image-loading

I'm trying to load an image into a game I just started to create, but when I do it's having trouble finding my image as can be seen below:

```
`Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
    at me.louisnathan.game.gfx.ImageLoader.loadImage(ImageLoader.java:12)
    at me.louisnathan.game.Game.init(Game.java:32)
    at me.louisnathan.game.Game.run(Game.java:60)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)`
```

The image is in a folder called textures which is in a another folder called res. The res folder had been added to the build path. My image is called image.png. The image was made in photoshop.

My code:

**Game class**

```
public class Game implements Runnable {

public int width, height;
public String title;

private Display display;
private Thread thread;
private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;
private BufferedImage image;

private boolean isRunning = false;

public Game(String title, int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.title = title;
}

private void init() {
    display = new Display(title, width, height);
    image = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/image.png");
}

private void tick() {

}

private void render() {
    bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();

    if (bs == null) {
        display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    // Clearing Screen
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    // Start Rendering



    // End Rendering
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}

public void run() {
    init();

    while (isRunning) {
        tick();
        render();
    }
}

public synchronized void start() {
    if (isRunning)
        return;
    isRunning = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    if (!isRunning)
        return;
    isRunning = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**ImageLoader Class**

```
public class ImageLoader {

public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: where in your Project `/textures/image.png` is located?

Comment: in my res folder which has been added to the build path

Comment: You are passing an absolute path to `loadImage`. Try a relative path, but you might need a little bit more work with that because I know there is some wizardry required when dealing with resources in Java--one of those things that are easier to brute-force until it works rather than learning how to work with them properly :-)

Comment: Sorry but how would I do that exactly? I'm not to familiar with paths and resources...

Comment: `which has been added to the build path` - don't know what the build path is but images should be found in your class path. `I'm not to familiar with paths and resources` - maybe the section from the Swing tutorial on [Loading Images Using Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource) will help. I don't use the leading "/".

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ wizardry? rly?

Comment: @Antoniossss Just trying to be funny. I can never get it right on the first attempt. It usually involves more print-debugging than should be necessary.

Comment: There is nothing magicat in there - just have to remember it starts with `/`

Answer (score 0):

This statement
`ImageLoader.class.getResource(path)` returns `null`.

Check generated JAR (you can opet it as any ZIP archive) or classes output directory (if running from IDE) if there is as file `image.png` in `textures` directory.

Comment: Exactly what I was referring to in my comment above: the need to poke around in the JAR file to figure out where the resource is :-)

Comment: Where/how do I check for the generated jar. The image.png is definitely in my textures folder that’s for sure.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely in res/textures folder

Comment: could it be something to do with configuring of the build path within the module path or classpath?

Comment: @Louis maybe it should be `/res/textures/` then? Its hard to tell not seeing project directory structure.

Comment: Nah because res is added to the build path so I shouldn’t need to. This is really tricky. I’ve actually never had a problem like this before. I feel like it could have something to do with the latest eclipse version.

Comment: *Nah because res is added to the build path so I shouldn’t need to* so what? What does build path has to do with it anyway? If in JAR you got /res/whatver/yourserouse than that is the path for resource.